# How do I diagnose a blinking overdrive off light on a 2001 Ford F-150 with 4R70W transmission?

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, diagnostics, f-150

Today the "OFF" light on the transmission shifter starting blinking on my 2001 Ford F-150. It is the 4.6L with a 4R70W transmission.

I pulled the codes but all I found was "Evap system inoperative" which is just caused by a loose gas cap. The CEL is not on. How do I determine why the light is blinking?